# What is the name of the solid created by joining two tetrahedra face-to-face?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d

When I connect the bases of two pyramids, I will receive an octahedron. I have a question about an analogical situation with two tetrahedra. What is the name of a geometrical figure, which is a combination of two tetrahedra?

Comment: I don't know any particulare name for such solid.

Comment: ["Triangular dipyramid"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularDipyramid.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [triangular dipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid), which is one of the $92$ Johnson solids (solids all of whose faces are regular but where the vertices do not all look the same).

Answer (score 2):

When joining two regular tetrahedra, the result is one of the Johnson solids, the [triangular bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid).

[image]

Two general tetrahedra joined face-to-face can also be called triangular bipyramids, but these joins are not Johnson solids.